# Having problem with routes.rb. No route matches show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am trying to make a button. When you click it, a modal should appear with a form.

I created the button:

```
<li>
<%= link_to content_tag(:i, nil, class: "fa fa-plus") + " New Rule",new_rule_correlation_engine_rule_path, class: "pull-right panel-button", 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#new_rule_correlation_engine_rule_modal", "data-backdrop" => "static" %>
</li>
```

And in the **routes.rb**, I defined the first route (the resources part was already there):

```
get 'correlation_engine_rules/new_rule' => 'correlation_engine_rules#new_rule', as: 'new_rule_correlation_engine_rule'

    resources :correlation_engine_rules do
      post :apply, on: :collection
    end
```

I also created a file named new_rule, with a logger at the beginning to know if this is being loaded. Apparently, when I click the button, it load that file, because I see the logger, but then I get this error:

```
<ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"correlation_engine_rules"} missing required keys: [:id]>
```

So, the routes matches with my first line, but it seems it is also trying to execute the method show, I guess because of the resources lines below mine. At first I had my route below that part, then I saw this error and I put it before, as stated in the routing rails guide, but I still get this error. I thought that when 1 route matches, it stop looking for more, maybe I am wrong but I don't get what is the problem. Thanks.

solution: i finally solved this by entering the new route inside the resources block, like this:

```
resources :correlation_engine_rules do
      post :apply, on: :collection
      get :new_rule, on: :collection
end
```

and then i'm calling it like new_rule_correlation_engine_rules_path.

Comment: Why do you think you should be duplicating the existing route / new action and breaking the conventions in the first palce? You already have a `new_correlation_engine_rule_path` route - use it.

Comment: I already have 1 button that calls that new method you are reefering too. The thing is that i want to do a total different thing, and also render a different view, so i though i would need to make this.  The button already made, calls new_correlation_engine _rule_path, as you said, and it render a file named 'new'. But now i want to render a file named new_rule, thats why i though about doing this. Im still learning rails so maybe this is very basic.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried specifying the http method GET?,something like this

```rb
<%= link_to content_tag(:i, nil, class: "fa fa-plus") + " New Rule",new_rule_correlation_engine_rule_path, method: :get, class: "pull-right panel-button", 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#new_rule_correlation_engine_rule_modal", "data-backdrop" => "static" %>
```